# Does not send my value from button and text over to my js file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is how I try to send my text above and also send my module ID over to my js file. I would have liked me to the enter the text you wrote and the id you got clicked.

The problem is that it comes back and gives me this:

**Hello world undefined - undefined**

It would have looked like this:

**Hello world 3 - Tetetew twt ewtewt**

What I'm trying to is that I need to send LektionerId from the button over to my js file and at the same time I send text over to my js file.

js - file here:

```
$scope.CheckValue = function () {
    console.log("Hello world " + $scope.LektionerId + " - " + $scope.Text);


    //$scope.$watch("OpgaveId", function () {
    //    var url = "/opgaver/CheckOpgave/" + $scope.LektionerId ;

    //    $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
    //        $scope.Newslist = response;
    //    });
    //});
}
```

index.html

```
<div ng-repeat="module in Newslist">
        <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" 
                       ng-model="Text" 
                       class="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Write your answer here" 
                       name="Text" />

                <button ng-click="CheckValue()"
                        ng-init="LektionerId='{{module.Id}}'" 
                        class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                        style="margin:6px 0;">
                    Check your answer
                </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*or should I try to put it all in a form?*

Comment: For what are you trying to use `ngModel` in a `button`?

Comment: It was a mistake. It is taken away. @developer033

Comment: @J.Petersen can you try putting `CheckValue(name)` to it?

Comment: You mean that I have to move `module.Id` up in `CheckValue(HER?)`

Comment: @J.Petersen well, `ngInit` has some purposes and it isn't one of them.. anyway.. try to remove the single quotes and the `{{}}`.

Comment: if i try its giv my button its here: `ng-init="LektionerId='module.Id'"` i make its `ng-init="LektionerId='module.Id'"` - I have taken {{}} away. but there are no numbers above.

Comment: @J.Petersen as I said, you should remove the single quotes also.

Comment: This is done now. @developer033

Comment: It seems, however, still does not ..

Comment: @J.Petersen Well, I Also said that `ngInit` shouldn't be used for this.. pass the `module.Id` as *parameter*, like this: `ng-click="checkValue(module.Id)"` then in your `function` -> `$scope.checkValue = function(id) ...`

Comment: Now it gives me nothing for my console.log @developer033 :(

Comment: @J.Petersen `console.log(id)` will give you the `module.Id`.

Comment: But the text does not appear at all. @developer033

Comment: Of course it doesn't.. `console.log("Hello world " + id + " - " + $scope.Text);`

Comment: @developer033 The text appears but id'en does not appear. Which I do not understand.

Comment: What do you have now..?

Comment: I have been based on the Nora have written the answers here. @developer033

Comment: And it's correct.. are you sure that you wrote the property correctly? Is it `id` or `Id`?

Comment: Yeaaa its work now!!! @developer033 Thanks to u and Nora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get each module value you should pass it like this:
`CheckValue(module)` and I would remove entrirely the `ng-init` (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/docs/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Atm all input fields you create within the loop are bound to the same model (`ng-model="Text"`). In case you want different values, then you will need to provide different models.

```
<div ng-repeat="module in Newslist">
        <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" 
                       ng-model="module.text" 
                       class="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Write your answer here" 
                       name="Text" />

                <button ng-click="CheckValue(module)" 
                        class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                        style="margin:6px 0;">
                    Check your answer
                </button>
        </div>
    </div>

$scope.CheckValue = function (module) {
    console.log("Hello world " + module.id + " - " + module.text);
}
```

Comment: You think that I have to do it like this `<input type="text" 
                        ng-model="Text"
                        ng-init="LektionerId='{{module.Id}}'"  
                        class="form-control" 
                        placeholder="Write your answer here" 
                        name="Text" />`

Comment: Hello I have provided examples

Comment: The text appears but id'en does not appear. Which I do not understand.

Comment: This work now. Thanks for help and i hope u will giv me +1 for my question